# How do I declare and call a function inside a class that extends Component in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner at React and am currently trying to learn by creating a Java Springboot and React application, sticking to MVC. I have a form and I wish to validate its input.

But how do I create and call the validation function in this class that extends Component? I tried to create it as "const validateValues" at first but I was given a compilation error. But I'm also given a compilation error on using function. I'm so far unable to find an answer while Googling. I'd also appreciate a good explanation to why this doesn't work and why I need to do different. Below is my code so far:

```
import './App.css';
import { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        rentalCars: []
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.getRentalCars();
    }

    async getRentalCars() {
        const response = await fetch('/rent');
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("GetRentalCars received from database: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        this.setState({ rentalCars: data });
    }

    render() {
        const {rentalCars} = this.state;
        const optionItems = rentalCars.map(({id, carName, rentalPricePerDay}, key) =>
            <option key={id} value={carName}> {carName}: {rentalPricePerDay} SEK/day</option>)

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <form className="registerForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <header className="Rental-cars">
                    <h2>Rent one of our cars!</h2>
                </header>
                    <label>
                        <p>First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" value={this.state.firstName} ref={node =>
                        (this
                        .inputNode = node)}
                        /></p>
                        <p>Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" value={this.state.lastName} /></p>
                        <p>Date of Birth: <input type="date" name="dateOfBirth" value={this.state.dateOfBirth} /></p>
                        <p>I want to rent a car from <input type="date" name="startDate" value={this.state.startDate}/>
                        to <input type="date" name="endDate" value={this.state.endDate} /></p>
                        <p>Car I wish to rent:
                            <select name="selectCar" ref={node => (this.inputNode = node)}>
                                {optionItems}
                            </select>
                        </p>
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let target = event.target;
        let formData = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
            formData[target.elements[i].getAttribute("name")] = target.elements[i].value;
        }
        let validationErrors = ValidateValues(formData);
        console.log('formData', formData);
    }

    function ValidateValues(inputValues){
        let errors = {};
        if(inputValues.firstName.length < 2
        || inputValues.firstName.length > 15
        || isNaN(parseInt(+inputValues.firstName))
        ) {
            errors.email = "You must enter a valid first name.";
        }
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: since you are doing this in an OOP way (not hooks), you have to call the function like this: `this.ValidateValues`. The other way is to declare the function as static and call it `App.ValidateValues`. Read more about the OOP in programming languages

Comment: @GeorgiStefkoff That might partly be because I got more experience as backend dev and OOP. Thank you for the tips, I'll look into what hooks are while at it.

Comment: Note that every other place you used functions here you did it correctly, by using `this.xxx`, which makes me want to ask if you're trying to move too fast through some basics. Tangentially: you're using at least two different ways of defining functions in the class--make sure you know why you're doing one or the other.

Comment: You may want to start w/ current React, too, if you're going to focus on React.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you for pointing that out! I see that now. I have limited time learning on my own and am definitely rushing due to stress. But the use of "function" in the code's current state is because the other way throws a compilation error and I'm tryin to figure out why I can't declare it in same manner.

Comment: "The other way" meaning...? There's three types of function defs: the normal ones (the async fns at the top), the arrow fn for the error handler, and the spurious `function` one at the bottom. Normal v arrow fns is a distinction worth understanding. The last function may have bene intended to not be in the class?

Comment: The same way you do the other places?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, that's what I meant. It turns out the problem all along was not how I declare the function but how I called it. A beginner's miss on my part. But you make a good point regarding looking deeper into the difference between normal v arrow fns, so I've added that too on my todo-list. Thank you!

Comment: It’s both. Arrow functions are bound to the instance, eg, a new function per instance. Regular functions (the async functions here) are on the prototype, similar to how some other class-based OO languages work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call a function/method by using the word this.
The syntax is "this." + the name of the method.
Try this.functionName